# Monotouch Phone/Call state?

Tags: iphone, ios, mono, xamarin.ios, core-telephony

Is there any way in Monotouch to read the current state on the phone or caller service?

Im trying to find some way of reading if a call is active or a call is on hold etc.

Googling on this haven't turned up anything.

Was looking to run some code snippet like:

```
if(CallIsActive) {

}
else {

}
```

My solution:

```
public static class CallHandler
{
private static CTCallCenter ctc;
private static NSSet calls;

public static void StartListening() {
    Console.WriteLine ("Callhandler is listening");
    ctc = new CTCallCenter ();
    calls = ctc.CurrentCalls;
    ctc.CallEventHandler = new CTCallEventHandler (delegate(CTCall inCTcall) {
            calls = ctc.CurrentCalls;

    });
    }

    public static uint CallCount {
        get {
            return (calls != null) ? calls.Count : 0;
        }
    }

    public static string GetCallState(int CallID) {
        CTCall[] callArr = calls.ToArray<CTCall>();
        CTCall call = callArr[CallID];
        return call.CallState;

    }
}
```

Run CallHandler.CallCount to get current callcount and GetCallState(0) for first call etc.

Comment: Anders,  for the sake of other people looking for the solution on StackOverflow, could you answer your own question with your own post?

Comment: Ok, i post my solution when I get back to work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the CoreTelephony framework. There is an Apple [sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CoreTelephonyDemo/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010746-ReadMe_txt-DontLinkElementID_7) that covers it.

```
using block-based event handlers to receive call events and carrier changes.
```

You'll need to convert the code from ObjectiveC to C# (look for **callStateToUser**).

Comment: This looks promising, to bad my Objective C skills are crap buy I think i will manage, will go over it tomorrow and if its portable i will mark ur answer as correct :)

Comment: You don't need to port the sample or even know much ObjectiveC beside looking at the API names being used and MonoTouch documentation, e.g. http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=N%3AMonoTouch.CoreTelephony - I don't have an iPhone to test it but it looks like using a CTCallCenter, set its CallEventHandler to your (C#) delegate and look at the provided CTCall State property (and track its value).

Comment: Im trying to get it working but as far as I can see this isn't portable :/. I create an instance of CTCallCenter but trying to fetch CurrentCalls always turns up as null. And i cannot define the calleventhandler either, it just crashes.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/46zGjqRr

Changed around some stuff to try and debug.. 

anyway all output:

Callhandler is active
No carrier
null
Could not map incomming calls?

Comment: nvm figured it out, thx for this!, had accidently taken a + when declaring the eventhandler :( and its null when having 0 calls, having a call when running the code made it work.